Does Romans 7:2-3 teach that only death ends a marriage?

2 For the married woman is bound by law to her husband as long as he
is alive; but if her husband dies, she is released from the law
concerning the husband. 3 So then, if while her husband is alive she
gives herself to another man, she will be called an adulteress; but if
her husband dies, she is free from the law, so that she is not an
adulteress if she gives herself to another man. (Romans 7:2-3, NASB
2020)

How does Romans 7:2-3, which states that a woman is bound to her husband as long as he lives but is free to remarry if he dies, reconcile with other biblical passages that seem to allow for divorce and remarriage in cases of sexual immorality or abandonment by an unbelieving spouse, as taught by Jesus in Matthew 19:9 and Paul in 1 Corinthians 7:15?
Does this passage leave room for divorce and remarriage under these specific circumstances, or does it suggest a stricter interpretation of the marital bond?

This passage isn’t intended to teach us a nuance about marriage and divorce, it is teaching us about the end of the Mosaic Law via comparison to the basic principles of marriage.
Marriage is intended to last until one party dies.  Starting a covenant between two people, beginning at the onset of marriage and having a set end (at ones death).
Paul is explaining that Mosaic Law is a similar covenant, beginning in the wilderness between Egypt and the Promised Land, and ending on the cross with Christ.

Rom 7:2, 3 teaches that a marriage is ended when one of the two partners dies.  However, it does not say that that is the only way to end a marriage - just that death, which is the subject Paul's topic, ends marriage.
Indeed, in 1 Cor 7:15, Paul notes that:

1 Cor 7:15 - But if the unbeliever leaves, let him go. The believing
brother or sister is not bound in such cases. God has called you to
live in peace.

Thus, death is just one of several ways that marriage could end.

In the same chapter of a different book :-) And assuming that "bound" equates to "married". Thank you, Dottard. Always appreciate your insight.

@TruthSeeker - OOPS!! I will correct that.  Thanks for pointing out that blooper!
